How to allow the terminal to make a bell noise in vs code
I have seen elsewhere that it is possible to make a terminal make a noise with cmd ^G (typed ctrl+G). I tried this and found it did nothing in the vs code terminal.
I'd give more details but all the relevant ones are in my answer.

I had 2 issues with making this work.
The first issue was that I was using bash for windows, which does not allow you to type the ctrl+g character I needed. Instead, the command is echo -en "\007", this uses the same Unicode character but includes it in a way that bash can understand. This fix came from here on stack overflow.
The second issue was that vs code was blocking the sound from being played, the fix was to enable the terminal bell in the accessibility settings.
This can be done with
...
"accessibility.signals.terminalBell": {
  "sound": "on"
}
...

or in the gui with features>accessibility signals>terminal bell


IMO, the simplest way and most readable way in bash for sending a bell to the terminal is printf %s $'\a' or echo -n $'\a', since \a is the common abbreviation for the BEL character in many programming languages. Of course sending octal 007 works as well.
